# How do I create a macro to perform a right click on a particular cell and choose an option from the right click menu?

Tags: vba, excel

I think the question is clear. I want to set a macro in Excel 2007 which performs the following tasks.
(1) Right clicks on a particular cell, say A1.
(2) Chooses(left clicks) an option from the right click menu.

What I actually need is to assign this macro to a command button.

Comment: Should it be a specific option? Should the process be visible (like the mouse hovering, right clicking, selecting) or does a simple execution of one of the right click menus options suffice?

Comment: Yes, a specific option. Don't want to see the process. Need a quick execution as how the usual excel macros do.

Comment: Any particular option? Always the same one?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: How do you determine which option of the menu has to be executed or is it always the same (like cut)? and if you click on that button, will it always be a particular cell (like you said, say A1) or could this vary?

Answer (score 1):

Go to VBA code editor (ALT+F11) and add new module (Insert->Module) then paste below code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const myBar As String = "MyPopupBar"


Sub CreatePopup()
Dim cmb As CommandBar
Dim ctr As CommandBarControl

DeletePopup

Set cmb = Application.CommandBars.Add(myBar, msoBarPopup)
Set ctr = cmb.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)

With ctr
    .Caption = "Click me"
    .OnAction = "ClickMe"
End With

cmb.ShowPopup

Set ctr = Nothing
Set cmb = Nothing

End Sub

Sub ClickMe()

    MsgBox "You clicked me!", vbInformation, "Wow!"

End Sub

Sub DeletePopup()

On Error Resume Next
Application.CommandBars(myBar).Delete

End Sub
```

Now, double click on Sheet1 module and add this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
CreatePopup
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

That's all!

**[EDIT]**
You're able to call popup menu from commandbutton, this way:

```
Application.CommandBars("TheNameOfCommandBarPopup").ShowPopup
```

For further information, please see:
[Creating Popup Menus in All Versions of Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg987030%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
[Customizing Context Menus in All Versions of Microsoft Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469862%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry. I think my question is not clear. I don't want to create a new right click menu. I need code to choose a particular candidate of the built in right click menu.

Comment: @JansonA.J, To be able to create custom popup containing builtin controls, use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862556%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

just some advice, not complete answer, but maybe a good start for you:

```
?application.commandbars("Cell").Controls(2).caption 'this is your 2nd action in right clic menu, can set it to a variable of type commandbarControl
```

&Copy

```
commandbars("Cell").Controls(2).execute 'will perform the action of what it is suposed to do when you clic it.
```

so maybe with a simple test (assuming you know what the Option will do):

```
with application.commandbars("Cell").Controls(2)
    if instr(1,.caption,"Copy")>0 then .execute
end with
```

EDIT : if option 2 is not the good one , you can replace 2 with a Long variable and loop throug the options.
EDIT 2 : i figured, you know how to select a particular cell , wich is actually the easy part...